# Firebase orderByKey().startAt() not working as expected. What's wrong?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to get firebase data from a node which uid must start with a passed string.

I tried a code but I always get the same data. The database data is as following:

[image]

And I'm using the following code:

```
var ref = firebase.database().ref("restaurantes/history");
    ref.orderByKey().startAt(userUID).once("child_added", function(snapshot) {
      snapshot.forEach(child => {
        if(child.key == "orders")
        {
          console.log(child.val());

          _.each(child.val(), (value, key) => {
            arrtmp.push(value)
          })
        }    

      })
```

If user is "FKQLlqa" I should get the history data shown in the picture. If I user is "abc" I shouldn't get any data. But I always get the data shown in the picture. Should I use another way of querying? Or I should use a key field inside orders and payments data?

Regards!

Answer (score 2):

Try the following:

```
var ref = firebase.database().ref("restaurantes/history");
ref.child(userUID).once("value", function(snapshot) {
  if (snapshot.exists()) {
      console.log(snapshot.val());
    }
  else {
      console.log("different user");    
  });
```

This will check if the snapshot that contains the `userId` (added as a parameter in the `child()` method), already exists in the database then you will be able to retrieve the data under the `userId`.

For reference:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.DataSnapshot#exists

Answer (score 1):

**Peter's answer is the correct solution.** I'm merely adding this for completeness.

When you call `orderBy...` on a Firebase reference, the database orders all child nodes on the key/value/child that you specify.

If you then subsequently call `startAt(...)` on the query, it finds the (first) node that starts with that value and *starts* returning all results from there. So if you start **at** `FKQLlqa`, it will start returning keys at `FKQLlqa` and then return all keys after it.

If you want to return the child node(s) with a specific key/value/child, you'd use `equalTo(...)`. So:

```
ref.orderByKey().equalTo(userUID).once("child_added", function(snapshot) {
  ...
```

But as Peter said already, this is just a more expensive way to look up a child with a known key. I highly recommend using his better approach: `ref.child(userUID).once("value"`.